# How can I iterate over all the batches from DataLoader?

Tags: pytorch, dataloader

I wanted to iterate over all the batches and save the images but with this process its saving only images of the first batch

```
    for batch_idx, (test_data, test_targets) in enumerate(test_loader):
        for i in range(0, test_loader.batch_size-1):
            img = np.array(test_data[i][0])*255
            img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
            hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
            low_black = np.array([0,0,0])
            high_black = np.array([360,255,0])
            mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, low_black, high_black)
            img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            img[mask>0]=random.choice(list(color_dict.values()))
            cv2.imwrite(f'/content/test_data/{test_targets[i].item()}_{i+1}.png', img)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `i` is start from `0` to `batch_size` at every batch so the saved names are duplicated. One common way to solve it is using `count`:

```py
count = 0 # here
for batch_idx, (test_data, test_targets) in enumerate(test_loader):
    for i in range(0, test_loader.batch_size-1):
        img = np.array(test_data[i][0])*255
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        low_black = np.array([0,0,0])
        high_black = np.array([360,255,0])
        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, low_black, high_black)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img[mask>0]=random.choice(list(color_dict.values()))
        cv2.imwrite(f'/content/test_data/{test_targets[i].item()}_{count}.png', img)
        count+=1 # plus one every sample
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the saved images only depends on `i` and `test_targets[i]`

```py
cv2.imwrite(f'/content/test_data/{test_targets[i].item()}_{i+1}.png', img)
```

So maybe all data are browsed but are overwritten batches after batches. It would be typically the case if `test_targets[i]` are redundant over batches for some fixed i.

To fix it, you can put `batch_idx` (that is unused here!) in the title too.